# fetch EKEvent from custom calendar return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

Recently I met this problem.

1, create a custom calendar (iCloud source)
2, add new event and save successfully, shown on device calendar.
3, save eventIdentifier in NSUserDefaults

But, 
When I use this method

```
EKEvent *event = [store eventWithIdentifier: identifier];
```

Always said: "Error getting event with identifier..."

This problem won't happen if I save event to default calendar.
Thanks for kindly help in advance.

Updated:
I make a demo with 4 buttons

1, create calendar,

2, search calendar using NSPredicate,

comparing the identifier, it is same.

3, create event,

4, search event using NSPredicate

also same.

What is wrong with calendarWithIdentifier & eventWithIdentifier?
if using these 2 methods, always return null.

Comment: IIRC there is the possibility of the identifier changing after the calendar syncs back to its server (in this case iCloud). Try dumping the events for the iCloud calendar just before `[store eventWithIdentifier: identifier]` to see if the event is actually there and what its ID is.

Comment: @norders Thank you. After saved event, and custom calendar, I use NSPredicate to search event and calendar. Both of the identifier are same! It seems eventWithIdentifier & calendarWithIdentifier not working. Do you know why?